# JSF + JS -> Execute Redirect only if everything is successful (Stripe)

Tags: javascript, jsf, stripe-payments

I have an order checkout page with using Stripe API.
I´m using JSF and the Stripe JS lib:

Here my GUI:
[image]

Here my JSF / JS code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
template="/WEB-INF/layout/portal/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="head" />
<ui:define name="title">Bestellseite</ui:define>


<ui:define name="content">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" />

                                <script>
    
                        // Set your publishable key: remember to change this to your live publishable key in production
                        // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
                        const stripe = Stripe('#{billingOrderProcessEditController.publicKey}');
                        
                        const options = {
                                  clientSecret: '#{billingOrderProcessEditController.paymentIntent.clientSecret}',
                
                                };
                

                                // Set up Stripe.js and Elements to use in checkout form, passing the client secret obtained in step 2
                                const elements = stripe.elements(options);
                
                                // Create and mount the Payment Element
                                const paymentElement = elements.create('payment');
                                paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');
                
                                
                                const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
                
                                form.addEventListener('submit', async(event) => {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                
                                    // Create BillingOrder
                                    createOrder();
                
                                    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
                                        //Elements instance that was used to create the Payment Element
                                        elements,
                                        confirmParams: {
                                            return_url: '#{billingOrderProcessEditController.redirectPage}',
                                        },
                                    });
                
                                    if (error) {
                                        // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
                                        // confirming the payment. Show error to your customer (e.g., payment
                                        // details incomplete)
                                        const messageContainer = document.querySelector('#error-message');
                                        messageContainer.textContent = error.message;
                                    } else {
                                        // Your customer will be redirected to your return_url. For some payment
                                        // methods like iDEAL, your customer will be redirected to an intermediate
                                        // site first to authorize the payment, then redirected to the return_url.
                                    }
                                });


                    </script>


                    <h:form id="payment-form" prependId="false">
                        <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">

                            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-6">

                                <p:panel id="billingOrderDetails_container"
                                    styleClass="grayPanel">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-lg"></i>
                                        <h:outputText value="Ihre Rechnungsdaten"
                                            styleClass="FontBold Fs12" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid"
                                        styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank grid-pad"
                                        style="margin-top:10px">

                                        <h:panelGroup id="billingOrder_surname_container">
                                            <p:outputLabel for="billingOrder_surname" value="Vorname:" />
                                            <p:inputText id="billingOrder_surname" required="true"
                                                requiredMessage="Bitte Vorname angeben"
                                                value="#{billingOrderProcessEditController.billingPaymentBearer.tempAddress.surname}"
                                                placeholder="Bitte Vorname eingeben" styleClass="Wid90">
                                                <p:ajax event="blur" update="@parent" global="false" />
                                            </p:inputText>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <div class="EmptyBox2"></div>



                                    </p:panelGrid>

                                </p:panel>
                            </div>


                            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-6">

                                <p:panel styleClass="grayPanel">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <i class="fa fa-eur fa-lg"></i>
                                        <h:outputText value="Ihre Zahlungsdaten"
                                            styleClass="FontBold Fs12" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
                                    </f:facet>


                                    <div id="payment-element">
                                        <!-- Elements will create form elements here -->
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="error-message">
                                        <!-- Display error message to your customers here -->
                                    </div>
                                </p:panel>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="EmptyBox10"></div>

                        <button id="submit"
                            jsf:rendered="#{billingOrderProcessEditController.billingOrder != null}"
                            onclick="startPayment(); PF('statusDialog').show();"
                            style="background-color: #4CAF50; border: 1px solid #4CAF50; border-radius: 3px; color: white; padding: 6px 16px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">
                            <span class="fa fa-save"></span> <span>Zahlungspflichtig
                                bestellen</span>
                        </button>

                        <p:remoteCommand name="startPayment"
                            update=":growl, @form:billingOrderDetails_container"
                            process="@form" />

                        <p:remoteCommand name="createOrder" async="true"
                            actionListener="#{billingOrderProcessEditController.doSaveOrderAndStartPayment()}" />

                    </h:form>
                </h:panelGroup>


                <div class="EmptyBox20"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</ui:define>
```

</ui:composition>

My issue is the following and I´m pretty sure I have to change something in the JS code:

- If I fillout the creditcard section (right) side and NOT the left side, the redirect will work.... But the redirect should only work, if the user fillout the right and left side.

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This is something for you to handle in your application logic. Essentially, you need to validate that your forms are filled to your requirements before you call `stripe.confirmPayment` to enter the payment flow.

You can do this multiple ways, such as by blocking the button until the forms are filled, or by checking the forms on the click handler event and surfacing some user feedback message about completing missing fields.

Comment: Yes, correct... But for this I would need help which I need to adopt in the code... There seems something wrong in combination with JSF and JS...

Comment: Can you help here?

Comment: You don't appear to have any code which attempts to validate the other details. Have you tried adding this? What doesn't work like you expect?